# What is executed in the NOT UI THREAD in a IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm not sure which parts of the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) are not executed on the UI thread. Can any one explain that a bit?

Comment: are you familiar with androidxref.com? if not see:  http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java#63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)` is called on a worker thread. The other callbacks are executed on the UI Thread